# Can't get image information with Telegram api and python

Tags: python, heroku, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I made a bot to receive images to `python` and work with them, all through `heroku`.
I made a simple page to see the information reveived like this:

```
@app.route('/apunteswaw',methods=['POST'])
def apunteswaw():
    data = json.loads(flask.request.data)
...
@app.route('/recive',methods=['GET'])
def recive():
    return 'Mensaje: {}'.format(data)
```

The page displays the last message sent, but when I send an image, it skips it and shows the last text message like this:

```
{'update_id': 54485500, 'message': {'message_id': 12, 'from': {'id': 231951870, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': '***', 'last_name': '***', 'language_code': 'en-US'}, 'chat': {'id': 231951870, 'first_name': '***', 'last_name': '***', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1525151196, 'text': 'asdasd'}}
```

How can I receive the photo data to download the picture sent from my `telegram` app through the `bot`?

Comment: I don't have a code for sending pictures, I only look to receive them. The picture is sent to my telegram bot, and the bot sends it to a webhook which corresponds to: appname.herokuapp.com/apunteswaw

Comment: Do you get any validation from the bot it has received the picture ? The JSON should contain a `photo` array where the image(s) should be when getting the last update.. Any more information on the flow of the app ?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That's true @Chris, quite a few answersnever get the correct answer, I thought the best thing was deleting them to prevent people to get to a dead end. What should I actually do? after a time the question is lost and never seen again.

Comment: @EvyatarMeged I set the webhook of the bot directly to `/apunteswaw`, so I should get everything there, unless there is a special configuration to get more info from a message, but I can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging more, I concluded that the Telegram API just doesn't send messages with media to the WebHook (Maybe it was just my case, but I just wouldn't know).

To get the pictures for the last message, you have to disable webhooks, and use the `getUpdates` method.

```
updates = requests.get('http://api.telegram.org/bot{}/getUpdates'.format(token))
if updates.status_code ==200:
    data = json.loads(updates.text)
    last = data['result'][-1]
    ide = ''
    if 'photo' in last['message']:
        foto = True
        ide = last['message']['photo'][2]['file_id']
    else:
        foto = False
        print('no photo')
    return foto, ide
```

From there the response includes the photo id to retrieve it with the method `getFile`:

```
r = requests.get('http://api.telegram.org/bot{}/getFile?file_id={}'.format(token,ide),)
if r.status_code == 200:
    path = json.loads(r.text)
    return path['result']['file_path']
```

Finally with the path you can download the picture with:
`'http://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<path>`

To get other media files like audio and video is the same procedure, but the id is found in another path of the response dictionary of `getUpdates`